# get-command : Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: powershell

I have `PowerShell 4` on a Windows 7 laptop.  I just installed PowerGUI, and discovered I am getting this error:

```
get-command : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Powershell_ISE, PowerShell Console, and PowerGUI, all throw this error when I do not pass a parameter with a command name. I cleared all profiles, and reinstalled `WMF 4.0` and `.Net 4.5`. I also updated everything including SQL and ... Nothing!

Later I found some of my scripts are working correctly. I then discovered that if I call a qualified command in a module that I have not loaded, it magically clears the error in that session only. When PS is forced to autoload a module the `Get-Command` and `Show-Command` start working.

Does anyone know why PowerShell started doing this and how to clear this condition?

Comment: I found a fix: I added the following statement to all of the PS profiles: $PSModuleAutoloadingPreference = "All"

Comment: You could post your comment as an answer. It is perfectly okay to answer your own question: http://superuser.com/help/self-answer